# Как сделать так, что бы при вводе человеком "Да" код повторялся с начала? Python

Tags: python

```
import random
print ('----------Угадай загаданное число----------')
print('Угадай случаенно выбраннаое компьютером число!')
print('Это рандомное число в диапазоне от 1 до 15')
magic_number = random.randint(1, 15) #выбирание рандомного числа
count = 0
user_number = 0
while user_number != magic_number:
  user_number = int(input('Твое число: '))
  count+=1
  if magic_number > user_number:
    print('Загаданное число больше твоего! Попробуй еще раз')
  elif magic_number < user_number:
    print('Загаданное число меньше твоего! попробуй еще раз')
print('Победа! Ты угадал число за', count, 'попыток!')
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import random
game = 'да'
while game.lower() == 'да':
    print ('----------Угадай загаданное число----------')
    print('Угадай случаенно выбраннаое компьютером число!')
    print('Это рандомное число в диапазоне от 1 до 15')
    magic_number = random.randint(1, 15) #выбирание рандомного числа
    count = 0
    user_number = 0
    while user_number != magic_number:
      npt = input('Твое число: ')
      if npt.isdigit():
          user_number = int(npt)
          count+=1
          if magic_number > user_number:
            print('Загаданное число больше твоего! Попробуй еще раз')
          elif magic_number < user_number:
            print('Загаданное число меньше твоего! попробуй еще раз')
      
    print('Победа! Ты угадал число за', count, 'попыток!')
    

    game = input('Продолжить игру? Для продолжения введите "да": ')
```

Comment: К вашей команде `while game == 'да'.lower():` — `'да'.lower()` то же самое, как `'да'`, да? Вы, наверно, хотели добавить `.lower()` за вашей последней командой, да? :-)

Comment: Вопрос, зачем присваивать переменной game = "нет "если на input Она в любом случае перезатрется вводом с клавиатуры?

Comment: @MarianD Задумывалось, что-бы было вот так `while game.lower() == 'да'`. Да!

Comment: @JvstTeo Вы правы. Исправил.

Comment: Правильно. Да! :-)

Comment: @MarianD Получается что правильно, Да! :-)